# C, realloc that fails if the allocation cannot grow IN PLACE

Tags: c, memory, resize, alloc

Is there a way to grow an array in C, but only if the memory can be grown in place (That is, fail to grow if the pointer needs to be changed)?

Comment: There is no standard way, though OS-specific functions to do/emulate something like that might exist or you could use memory pool and implement it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In standard C there is no function capable of doing that.