# Memory allocation that resizes a buffer ONLY if it can grow in place?

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

After reading the man-page for `realloc()`, I came to the realization that it works a little differently than I thought it did. I originally thought that `realloc()` would attempt to resize a buffer, previously allocated with one of the malloc-family functions, and if it could NOT extend the buffer *in place*, then it would fail. However, the man-page states:

> The realloc() function returns a pointer to the newly allocated memory, which is suitably aligned for any built-in type and may be different from ptr, or NULL if the request fails.

The **"may be different from ptr"** part is what I'm talking about.

Basically, what I want is a function, similar to `realloc()`, but which fails if it cannot extend the buffer *in place*. It seems that there is no function in the standard C library that does this; however, I'm assuming there may be some OS-specific functions that accomplish the same thing.

Could someone tell me what functions are out there that do what I described above, and which OS's they are specific to? Preferably, I'd like to know at least the functions specific to Linux and Windows (and Mac OS would be a nice bonus too :) ).

This may be a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21630787/c-realloc-that-fails-if-the-allocation-cannot-grow-in-place), but I don't think it is for the following reasons:

1. The question in the post I linked to simply asks, *is there* a function that extends a buffer in place, whereas, I'm asking, *which* functions extend a buffer in place.
2. The accepted answer for that post does not contain the information I need.

#### EDIT

Some people were wondering what is the use case I need this for, so I'll explain, below:

I'm writing a C preprocessor (yes, I know... don't reinvent the wheel... well, I'm doing it anyways, so there). And one component of the C preprocessor is a cache for storing pp-tokens which come from various source files, where each source file's set of pp-tokens may be fragmented within the cache. The cache itself, is a linked-list of large chunks of memory. Ideally, I'd like to keep this linked-list short, hence why I'd like to first try resizing the buffer (in place); however, if resizing in place is not possible, then I want to just add another node (i.e. chunk of memory) to the linked list.

Within each cache buffer, there are additional linked-list nodes, which provide a means for iterating through all the pp-tokens of each individual source file, which may be fragmented across the various cache buffers that make up the cache.

The reasons I need the kind of memory reallocation I discussed earlier are the following:

1. If resizing a cache buffer could not be done in place, and a new buffer had to be allocated and the old memory contents copied, then I'd have a lot of dangling pointers. [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) suggested that I instead store offsets within the buffer, rather than pointers, which I had not even thought about, and is a great idea! However, reason #2...
2. I want the implementation of the cache to be as fast as possible, and, please correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems to me that (for my use case) it would be faster on average to just add a new cache buffer to the linked list if a given cache buffer could not be resized in place, rather than allocating a new buffer and copying all previous contents and freeing the old buffer. As a sidenote, I am planning on doubling the size of the allocated cache buffer each time cache resizing is needed.

Comment: C does not have such a function. Why would you care if `realloc` allocates a separate block of memory of sufficient size and copies your existing data to it, freeing the original and returning a pointer to the new block on success, `NULL` otherwise. Can you explain why you think you need the same block extended? You could look at `mmap`, but I'm not sure that guarantees the same block. (I think you are confusing -- extending a buffer in-place and allocating storage for that extended buffer?)

Comment: Just curious, why would you need that? Most likely you are looking for the solution  for the problem that does not exist..

Comment: I've not heard of such a function on any Unix-like platform, but it could exist or be created.  If the problem is that you're storing pointers within the allocated space that break when the allocation is moved, the main answer is "don't do that — use offsets instead of pointers".  That is, instead of a pointer, store an offset from the start of the chunk.  Then, when you need to access it, take the current start address of the chunk and add the appropriate offset to get to the data.  This works correctly (with care) even if the base address is changed by `realloc()` moving the data around.

Comment: Because malloc mostly uses sbrk() which *increments* a heap pointer if more memory is needed, the next malloc will deliver a block just on top of the previous, so the previous cannot grow at the same place.

Comment: @holger: that's not a common malloc implementation strategy these days. You might find it in some minimal embedded system, but it is certainly not how malloc works on common desktop operating systems.

Comment: @Holger while that is true, it is very uncommon to have *only the last bytes* there.

Comment: OP: what exactly is the use case for this - possible answers depend on the use!

Comment: I've updated my question to explain the use-case for what I'm asking for. Also, big thanks to [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) for the great idea regarding offsets, rather than pointers. However, I still have not been convinced that I do not actually need what I'm asking for. However, if you have a different opinion, please throw your arguments at me! I'm open to all suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Memory management (in the form of `malloc` and friends) is generally implemented as a library; it is not part of the Operating System. (An implementation of the library will probably need to use some OS facilities to acquire raw memory -- although that's not a given -- but there is no need to involve the OS for allocating and freeing individual allocations.) So you're not going to find an "OS-specific" solution.

There are a number of different memory allocation libraries available. If you decide to use an alternative to the one preinstalled with your particular distribution, you will probably want to arrange for it to be used by the standard library as well. Details for how to do that vary.

Most allocation libraries do include some additional interfaces, but I don't know of any library which offers the function you're looking for. More common is an API for finding out how much memory is actually in an allocation (which is often more than the amount requested by the `malloc`). For many libraries, `realloc` will only expand the allocation in place if it was already big enough, but there may be libraries which are willing to merge a following free block in order to make non-copying `realloc` possible.

There's a list of some commonly-used libraries in the Wikipedia page on [dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation#Implementations), which also has a good overview of implementation techniques.

And, of course, you could always write your own memory manager (or modify an open source library) to implement that feature. However, while that would be an interesting and satisfying project, I'd strongly suggest you think about (and research) the reasons why this seemingly simple idea has not been implemented in common memory management libraries. There are good reasons.